# .NET 6.0 Razor Pages unable to connect to the localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working through some tutorials on Razor Pages using .NET 6.0 and have found that my computer is not wanting to find the localhost when running the application. If I create a basic .NET Core Web App using .NET 5.0 then everything works but if I do the same with .NET 6.0 then it doesn't load, even without any changes.

The message I receive is:
This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7273/
HTTP ERROR 404

I can open the same project on another computer and everything works as expected. I assume there is something with local setup that is causing this since the standard template for a .NET Core Web App using .NET 6.0 won't even work.

I have attempted to install the .NET Core 6.0 SDK, the Core Runtime, and the Desktop Runtime and nothing changed.

My launch settings file is:
[LaunchSettings.json Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzCnI.png)
And my Program.cs is: [Program.cs Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSaoD.png)

I've spent hours searching various forums but there seems to be very little available for .NET 6.0 and nothing seems to hit what I need, especially since the default starter template for a .NET Core Web App won't even work.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find another post that actually matched the issue I was having. The post can be found here: [.NET 6 Core Web App Returns web page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71456994/net-6-core-web-app-returns-web-page-not-found)

I was able to confirm that building through dotnet build in the command line did work but I would have to do that every time I made a code change. I then updated visual studio and it works now.